# Multivariable calculus converting from cartesian coordinates to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I convert this from cartesian coordinates to cylindrical coordinates? I am really confused.

$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^4 (x) \ dz \ dy\ dx$$

I changed it from

$$\int_2^2 \int_\pi^0 \int_{r^2}^4 r^2\cos(\theta) \ dz \ dr\ d\theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^4 (x) \ dz \ dy\ dx =\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{r^2}^4r^2 \cos \theta \,dz\, dr\, d\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

You can see the $xy$ make a whole circle. So the limits for $\theta$ should be $0,2\pi$, and the limits for $r$ should be $0,2$.

Also, you should switch your $dr$ and $d\theta$, so that they are consistent with the integration limits.